# Show $\|v_{n+1}-\langle v_{n+1},a_1\rangle a_1-...-\langle v_{n+1},a_n\rangle a_n\|=\det(A_n)$ where $A_n=(\langle v_1,v_j\rangle)_{1\le i,j\le n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inner-products, gram-schmidt

Let $V$ be an inner product space. Let$(v_1,v_2,...)$ be a sequence of linearly independent vectors in $V$ and let$$a_1=\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|},a_{n+1}=\frac{v_{n+1}-\langle v_{n+1},a_1\rangle a_1-...-\langle v_{n+1},a_n\rangle a_n}{\|v_{n+1}-\langle v_{n+1},a_1\rangle a_1-...-\langle v_{n+1},a_n\rangle a_n\|}$$Show that $\|v_{n+1}-\langle v_{n+1},a_1\rangle a_1-...-\langle v_{n+1},a_n\rangle a_n\|=det(A_n)$ where $A_n=(\langle v_1,v_j\rangle )_{1\le i,j\le n}$

I already proved that $(a_1,a_2,...)$ is a orthonormal sequence and I am wondering how to deal with $\det(A_n)$.

Comment: Do you mean $A_n=\left(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle\right)$?

Comment: The LHS depends on $v_{n+1}$ but the RHS doesn't. eg if $V=\mathbb R^2$, $v_1=a_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,k)$ then the LHS is $\|v_2\|=|k|$ but the RHS is $\langle v_1,v_1\rangle=1$.

Comment: Actually $A_n$  is a $n*n$ matrix.